# Send Push Notifications programmatically

Tags: android

I've implemented PushBots that uses GCM  on my app for sending push notifications ... However the only way I can send push notifications is through the PushBots site ..

I want to be able to send those notifications programmatically with no website at all ..

Any idea's how to do that ? thanks.

Comment: What event would fire a push notification ? Is it server side, client side ?

Comment: I need that one android device (server) will send the messsage to another lets say 20 android device's (clients) that the app is installed at all the devices.

Comment: Yes With parse you can do that ...