# Send message to multiple people

Tags: android

I want to send a message from one device to a couple devices ( like 20 devices and more ).
Push notifications is not an option because you send the notifications from a site..  i need to send the message programmatically.

is ther any good approach to that? I thought about Data sms message ... But would like to hear from you what you think ?

Note: from my preview question: [Send Push Notifications programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874150/send-push-notifications-programmatically)

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: That's why im asking... ther's alot of options and thats what i'd like to hear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Push notifications is not an option because you send the notifications
>   from a site

Not necessarily. You can use the [`Parse SDK`](https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications) for example to send push notifications directly from the phone to other phones.

Comment: Thanks thats sounds interesting but can i send those notifications when the user press a button to another 20 devices?

Comment: Yes, you can. I would suggest you go through their docs, they are pretty informative of all the things you can do with the Parse SDK; it is much more than just the push feature.

Comment: Well i did solved it in the same way but from another site called : App42... But the idea came from you so thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can build something like server.. When user register he will send sms to your phone. Your app will be a listener to sms with specific text.
In case you get sms with keyword you save the device details on android DB.

You need to create screen in order to send notification to the user

Send sms programically: 
http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-sms-message-in-android/

Sms Listener:
http://androidexample.com/Incomming_SMS_Broadcast_Receiver_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=62&aaid=87

Send notification GCM:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

I guess you can search for someone who provide this service.. But you can build it by yourself with something like i described.. All the info here..

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks i did implemented sms listener for data messages But im not sure if push notification is better then data messages...

Comment: I think notification is better.. If you will find the proper service that does this.